# Mauritus national flag problem

Tags: algorithm, scheme

I've made a solution for the [Dutch national flag problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem) already.

But this time, I want to try something more difficult: the Mauritus national flag problem - 4 colours, instead of 3. Any suggestions for an effective algorithm?

Basically, The Mauritius National Flag Problem focuses on how you would be able to sort the given list of pairs based on the order of colors in the Mauritius National Flag (Red, Blue, Yellow, Green). And the numbers must be sorted in ascending order too.

Scheme Programming Sample Input:

( (R . 3) (G . 6) (Y . 1) (B . 2) (Y . 7) (G . 3) (R . 1) (B . 8) )

Output:

( (R . 1) (R . 3) (B . 2) (B . 8) (Y . 1) (Y . 7) (G . 3) (G . 6) )

Comment: No, actually we don't all know what the Dutch national flag problem is. I've also edited your question to remove all the upper case text.

Comment: Well now that we know it's actually a CS problem, maybe the closers will reconsider their decisions?

Comment: Uneccessary to close this, as it is an interesting question. But it could definately be rephrased to describe the problem better. Also I'm not really sure there even is any solutions to this algorithm problem.

Comment: After the edits, this question is quite clear IMO.

Comment: Vote to reopen because I am a Mauritian. (among other reasons)

Comment: This challenge also involves the idea of effciency, and the solution should not use any extra arrays, and it should ideally inspect or move each value as few times as it can. Strictly expressed like this: "The cost of moving a ball or, equivalently, examining the color of a ball is so high that it can be done once only for each ball."

Comment: [Tag \[dutch-national-flag\] name and definition?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368049/tag-dutch-national-flag-name-and-definition) . @MarkByers et al.

Comment: This one should be merged into this: [Dutch national flag algorithm with four colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893890/dutch-national-flag-algorithm-with-four-colors)

Answer (score 8):

Here is what I came up with. Instead of colors, I am using numbers.

```
// l  - index at which 0 should be inserted.
// m1 - index at which 1 should be inserted.
// m2 - index at which 2 should be inserted.
// h  - index at which 3 should be inserted.
l=m1=m2=0;
h=arr.length-1
while(m2 <= h) {
    if (arr[m2] == 0) {
        swap(arr, m2, l);
        l++;

        // m1 should be incremented if it is less than l as 1 can come after all
        // 0's
        //only.
        if (m1 < l) {
            m1++;
        }
        // Now why not always incrementing m2 as we used to do in 3 flag partition
        // while comparing with 0? Let's take an example here. Suppose arr[l]=1
        // and arr[m2]=0. So we swap arr[l] with arr[m2] with and increment l.
        // Now arr[m2] is equal to 1. But if arr[m1] is equal to 2 then we should
        // swap arr[m1] with arr[m2]. That's  why arr[m2] needs to be processed
        // again for the sake of arr[m1]. In any case, it should not be less than
        // l, so incrmenting.
        if(m2<l) {
            m2++;
        }       
    }
    // From here it is exactly same as 3 flag.
    else if(arr[m2]==1) {
        swap(arr, m1, m2)
        m1++;
        m2++;           
    }
    else if(arr[m2] ==2){
        m2++;
    }
    else {
        swap(arr, m2, h);
        h--;
    }           
}


}
```

Similarly we can write for five flags.

```
    l=m1=m2=m3=0;
    h= arr.length-1;
    while(m3 <= h) {
        if (arr[m3] == 0) {
            swap(arr, m3, l);
            l++;
            if (m1 < l) {
                m1++;
            }
            if(m2<l) {
                m2++;
            }
            if(m3<l) {
                m3++;
            }

        }
        else if(arr[m3]==1) {
            swap(arr, m1, m3);
            m1++;
            if(m2<m1) {
                m2++;
            }
            if(m3<m1) {
                m3++;
            }   

        }
        else if(arr[m3] ==2){
            swap(arr,m2,m3);
            m2++;
            m3++;
        }
        else if(arr[m3]==3) {
            m3++;
        }
        else {
            swap(arr, m3, h);
            h--;
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

This is just like the Dutch national flag problem, but we have four colors.  Essentially the same strategy applies.  Assume we have (where ^ represents the point being scanned).

```
  RRRRBBB???????????YYYYGGGG
         ^
```

and we scan a

1. red, then we swap the first blue with the current node
2. BLUE we do nothing
3. yellow we swap with the last ?
4. Green we swap the last yellow with the last ? Then the current node with the swapped ?

So we need to keep track or one more pointer than usual.

We need to keep track of the first blue, the first ?, the last ?, the last Y

In general, the same strategy works for any number of colors, but an increasing numbers of swaps are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, maintain the following :

```
a[0-p] => '0'
a[p-q] => '1'
a[q-r] => '2'
a[r-s] => traversing! 
a[s-length] => '3'
```

Code:

```
        int p=-1,q=-1,r=0,s=a.length-1;
        while(r<=s){
            if(a[r]==0){
                exchange(a,p+1,r);
                p++;r++;
                if(q!=-1)
                    q++;
            } else if (a[r]==1){
                if(q==-1)
                    q=p;
                exchange(a,q+1,r);
                q++;r++;
            } else if(a[r]==2) {
                r++;
            } else {
                exchange(a,r,s);
                s--;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do have a similar kind of code but insted of

```
function sort(a:string[]){    
         let low = 0;
         let mid1 = 0;
         let mid2 = a.length-1;
         let high = a.length-1;

        while(mid1 <= mid2){
             switch(a[mid1]){

                 case '0':

                        [a[mid1],a[low]] = [a[low],a[mid1]];
                        mid1++;
                        low++;
                        break;

                 case '1':mid1++;break;

                 case '2':
                 case '3':[a[mid1],a[mid2]] = [a[mid2],a[mid1]];
                            mid2--;
                            break;

                 }
         }
    //sort 2 and 3
         while(mid1 <= high){
          switch(a[mid1]){
                 case '2': mid1++; break;
                 case '3': [a[mid1],a[high]] = [a[high],a[mid1]]
                            high--;
                            break;

           }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sort3(a:string[]):void{
    let low = 0;
    let mid1 = 0;
    let mid2 = 0;
    let high = a.length - 1;
    while(mid2<=high){
        switch(a[mid2]){
            case '0': [a[mid2],a[low]] = [a[low],a[mid2]];
                    low++;
                    if(mid1<low)
                    mid1++;
                    if(mid2<mid1)
                    mid2++;
                    break;

            case '1': [a[mid2],a[mid1]] = [a[mid1],a[mid2]];
                    mid1++;
                    mid2++;
                    break;

            case '2':mid2++
                   break;

            case '3':[a[mid2],a[high]] = [a[high],a[mid2]];
                    high--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
let a:string[] = ['1','2','1','0','2','4','3','0','1','3'];

function sort3(a:string[]):void{
    let low = 0;
    let mid1 = 0;
    let mid2 = 0;
    let mid3 = 0;
    let high = a.length - 1;
    while(mid3<=high){
        switch(a[mid3]){
            case '0': [a[mid3],a[low]] = [a[low],a[mid3]];
                    low++;
                    if(mid1 < low)
                    mid1++;
                    if(mid2 < mid1)
                    mid2++;
                    if(mid3 < mid2)
                    mid3++;
                    break;

            case '1': [a[mid3],a[mid1]] = [a[mid1],a[mid3]];
                    mid1++;
                    if(mid2 < mid1)
                    mid2++;
                    if(mid3 < mid2)
                    mid3++
                    break;

            case '2': [a[mid2],a[mid3]] = [a[mid3],a[mid2]];
                        mid2++;
                        mid3++;
                   break;

            case '3':
                    mid3++;break;

            case '4': [a[mid3],a[high]] = [a[high],a[mid3]];
                        high--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.