# Dutch national flag algorithm with four colors

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, dutch-national-flag-problem

I went through a solution for two and three colors but I am unable to get it for four colors.

Please help.

Will it be `rrbb????yyyggg`?
How will we swap the green flag?

I tried the solution below but it is not working with swapping the last yellow with green.

```
  public class count123 {

// Java program to sort an array of 0, 1 and 2,3

    static void sort0123(int a[], int arr_size)
    {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = arr_size - 1;
        int mid = 0,temp=0;
        int h2=arr_size - 1;
        while (mid <= hi)
        {
            switch (a[mid])
            {
            case 0:
            {
                temp = a[lo];
                a[lo] = a[mid];
                a[mid] = temp;
                lo++;
                mid++;
                break;
            }
            case 1:
                mid++;
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                temp = a[mid];
                a[mid] = a[hi];
                a[hi] = temp;

                hi--;
                h2=hi;
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                temp = a[mid];
                a[mid] = a[h2];
                a[h2] = temp;
            //  h2--;
                //hi=h2;
                break;

            }
            }
        }
    }

    /* Utility function to print array arr[] */
    static void printArray(int arr[], int arr_size)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
            System.out.println("");
    }

    /*Driver function to check for above functions*/
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int arr[] = {0, 1, 0,1,2,2,0,3,3,0,0,1};
        int arr_size = arr.length;
        sort0123(arr, arr_size);
        System.out.println("Array after seggregation ");
        printArray(arr, arr_size);
    }
}
/*This code is contributed by Devesh Agrawal*/
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it in such convoluted way? Either write/use proper sorting algorithm which can handle any integers, or if you really need just 4 values, use simplest bucket sort (count how many 0,1,2,3 there are in the list and then recreate it accordingly).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mauritus national flag problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433797/mauritus-national-flag-problem)

Answer (score 2):

I run your code and realized that your code goes into *infinite loop*, which let does your programm do nothing.

In the main method, `sort0123(arr, arr_size);` is called and within this method,         `while (mid <= hi)`, mid = 6 and hi = 9 and that means `6 <= 9` and because of this resaon, this condition returns true infinitely because of the fact that it goes always to the case 3 at some point and in the case 3, the values of mid and hi are not changed.

In order to be able to run your code, you should change the value(s) of `mid` and/or `hi` logically and with it, your program can behave, how you wanted.

Comment: That i know but i am unable to get a solution for this

Comment: @coder25 Honestly, I did not understand what you are asking for. If you kindly are able to edit your question with more detail, I may help you better.

Comment: @coder25 You can also have a look at the following question. His solution is almost complete. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706636/dutch-national-flag-not-working-for-larger-array?rq=1   and also, look at the following; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem

Answer (score 1):

The point about dutch flag aggregation is that invariants are always maintained. In a state such as 0000...11..XXX..222

1. lo will always be at the first '1' (if it exists)
2. mid will always be at the first unknown
3. hi is always at the last unknown

For the 4 colour variation, assuming that you are sorting in order 0,1,3,2 as seems to be the case from the code, the rules will need to be tweaked as follows:

3. hi is always at the last 3
4. h2 is always at the last unknown

Following the above rules, the code will need to be changed in the following ways:

`while (mid <= h2)`

.
.
.

```
case 2:
        {
            temp = a[mid];
            a[mid] = a[hi];
            a[hi] = temp;

            hi--;
            h2--;
            break;
        }
case 3:{
            temp = a[mid];
            a[mid] = a[h2];
            a[h2] = temp;
            h2--;
            break;

        }
```

For sorting in order 0,1,2,3 simply interchange the case statements of '2' and '3'.

**PS: Please make the question descriptive to help people understand the problem with ease.**

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, written in python. The rationale behind it is to squeeze the forth color (middle right color) in between the middle left and right sub-arrays. It defines the colors as the algorithm progresses.

It has a O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity

```python
from typing import List

def dutch_variant_four_colors(array: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    left = array[0]
    mid_left = None
    right = None

    left_i = 0
    mid_left_i = 0
    mid_right_i = len(array)
    right_i = len(array)

    while mid_left_i < right_i and mid_left_i < mid_right_i:
        if (array[mid_left_i] == left):
            array[mid_left_i], array[left_i] = array[left_i], array[mid_left_i]
            mid_left_i += 1
            left_i += 1
        elif (right is None or array[mid_left_i] == right):
            right_i -= 1
            mid_right_i = right_i
            array[mid_left_i], array[right_i] = array[right_i], array[mid_left_i]
            right = array[right_i]
        else:  # it is a mid value
            if (mid_left is None):
                mid_left = array[mid_left_i]
            if (array[mid_left_i] == mid_left):
                mid_left_i += 1
            else:
                mid_right_i -= 1
                array[mid_left_i], array[mid_right_i] = array[mid_right_i], array[mid_left_i]

    return array


# Sample usages
print(dutch_variant_four_colors([1,1,3,3,4,3,2,2]))
print(dutch_variant_four_colors([1,2,3,4,2,3,1,3]))
print(dutch_variant_four_colors([1,2,3,4,4]))
print(dutch_variant_four_colors([0,1,2,5,5,2,2,0]))
print(dutch_variant_four_colors([1,0,3,0,5,5]))
print(dutch_variant_four_colors([1,2,3,2,5,1,1,3]))
print(dutch_variant_four_colors([5,1,2,3,2,1,1,3]))
print(dutch_variant_four_colors([3,2,5,1]))
print(dutch_variant_four_colors([3,2,1,5]))
print(dutch_variant_four_colors([3,2,1,3,5,2,2,1,2,3,5,3,2,1,3,5,3,3,2,2,2,5,5,5,3,3,2,5,3,1,2,3,2,1,3,2,1,1,2,3,2,3,2,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,2,2,1,1,2,3]))
```

Gist available on https://gist.github.com/lopespm/81a336871ce6074f63f3cad349c3a95d

Answer (score 1):

```
let a:string[] = ['1','2','1','0','2','4','3','0','1','3'];
    function sort3(a:string[]):void{
        let low = 0;
        let mid1 = 0;
        let mid2 = 0;
        let mid3 = 0;
        let high = a.length - 1;
        while(mid3<=high){
            switch(a[mid3]){
                case '0': [a[mid3],a[low]] = [a[low],a[mid3]];
                        low++;
                        if(mid1 < low)
                        mid1++;
                        if(mid2 < mid1)
                        mid2++;
                        if(mid3 < mid2)
                        mid3++;
                        break;

                case '1': [a[mid3],a[mid1]] = [a[mid1],a[mid3]];
                        mid1++;
                        if(mid2 < mid1)
                        mid2++;
                        if(mid3 < mid2)
                        mid3++
                        break;

                case '2': [a[mid2],a[mid3]] = [a[mid3],a[mid2]];
                            mid2++;
                            mid3++;
                       break;

                case '3':
                        mid3++;break;

                case '4': [a[mid3],a[high]] = [a[high],a[mid3]];
                            high--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

[My solution in ideone](https://ideone.com/q6U7wF)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



void DutchNationalFlag4(int * arr , int n )
{
    int low = 0 , mid1 = 0 , mid2 = n- 1 , high = n-1 ;
    int temp;
 
    // This type of problems are best solved by using invariants 
 
    // arr[ 0 .. low -1 ] conatins 0
    // arr[ low .. mid1 -1 ] contains 1
    // arr[ mid1 .. mid2 ] is unknown
    // arr[ mid2 + 1 ... high - 1 ] contains 2
    // arr[ high .. n-1 ] contains 3
 
    // termination condition : Evert Iteration unkown length decreases so eventually will be Zero
    while( mid1 <= mid2 )
    {
        switch( arr[ mid1 ])
        {
            case 0 :
            {
                std::swap( arr[ low ] , arr [ mid1 ] );
                low ++ ;
                mid1 ++;
                break;
            }
 
            case 1 :
            {
                mid1 ++;
                break;
            }
 
            case 2 :
            {
                std::swap( arr[ mid1 ] , arr[ mid2 ]);
                mid2 -- ;
                break;
            }
 
            case 3 :
            {
                std::swap( arr[ mid1 ] , arr[ mid2 ]);
                std::swap( arr[ mid2 ] , arr[ high ]);
                mid2 --;
                high --;
                break;
            }
 
        }
    }
 
    for( int i =0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[ i ] << " " ;
    }
}
 
int main() 
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,0,2,1,3,0,2,1,0,1,3,1,0,2,1,0};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) ;
    DutchNationalFlag4(arr , n );
    return 0;
}
```

I have solved it in the above link!
Cheers

Please try to be more clear when you are asking a question. And also make sure your variables are either named intuitively or you have provided appropriate comments.
Frankly I was confused with hi and h2 , mid !

Answer (score 0):

```
//Dutch National Flag for N different values Optimized 
//O(n) optimized solution.
//O(1) space needed where x is distinct colors (it will not change as no. of values increases)

public static void DutchNationalFlagforNvaluesOptimized(int distinctFlags, int[] flags)
        {
            int high = distinctFlags - 1, mid = distinctFlags - 2;

            int[] indexArr = new int[distinctFlags];
            for (int i = 0; i < high; i++)
            {
                indexArr[i] = 0;
            }
            indexArr[high] = flags.Length - 1;// index Array is distinct flags indexes


            for (; indexArr[mid] <= indexArr[high]; )
            {
                if (flags[indexArr[mid]] == high)
                {
                    int temp = flags[indexArr[high]];
                    flags[indexArr[high]] = flags[indexArr[mid]];
                    flags[indexArr[mid]] = temp;

                    indexArr[high]--;
                }
                else
                    if (flags[indexArr[mid]] == mid)
                    {
                        indexArr[mid]++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int currentMidValue = flags[indexArr[mid]];

                        for (int i = mid; i > currentMidValue; i--)
                        {
                            int temp = flags[indexArr[i]];
                            flags[indexArr[i]] = flags[indexArr[i - 1]];
                            flags[indexArr[i - 1]] = temp;
                            indexArr[i]++;
                        }
                        indexArr[currentMidValue]++;
                    }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < flags.Length; i++)
            {
                System.Console.Write(flags[i] + ", ");
            }
        }
```